# Access newly added DOM elements after createComponent is called on a ViewContainerRef

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dom

I have a current block of code for creating dynamic components and generating a table of contents after components are added to DOM (service does things like grab all h3 elements from DOM so that it can be added to table of contents):

```
  generateDynamicComponents(): void {
this.someService.pageContent$
  .subscribe((page: CmsDto.Page) => {
    page.groups
      .filter((group: CmsDto.Group) => !isNullOrUndefined(dynamicComponentMap()[group.type]))
      .forEach((group: CmsDto.Group) => {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver
          .resolveComponentFactory(dynamicComponentMap()[group.type]);
        const viewHost: ViewContainerRef = this.dynamicComponentHostDirective.viewContainerRef;
        const componentRef = viewHost.createComponent(componentFactory);
        (componentRef.instance as DynamicArticleBaseComponent).group = group;
    });
    // set timeout to get around the time of components being created and added to DOM.
    setTimeout(() => this.tableOfContentsService.generateTableOfContents());
  });
}
```

Is there a way to know when these components are created and ready to be selected in the DOM without needing to use `setTimeout`? I wanted to use something like ContentChildren, but I cannot select h3 elements using that and instead am stuck using `document.querySelectorAll('h3');` since you can't select base HTML elements that aren't tagged with an `#id`.

Comment: Have you looked into using the `AfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook?

Comment: "(service does things like grab all h3 elements from DOM so that it can be added to table of contents)" -- you're aproaching this the wrong way. You're supposed to use directives for this.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel yes, I got it to work using AfterViewChecked, but one problem I ran into was the infamous ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError since within my tableOfContentsService I emit events from a `ReplaySubject` that another component listens to and gets an update from and so if this happens within the lifecycle, Angular gives me an error.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović could you elaborate a bit on that? Not sure what I am supposed to be using a directive for instead.

Comment: Is there a reason you are manually trying to go through the DOM to see when content is rendered? Your data should drive your templates and not the other way around

Comment: For querying the `h3` element. Use a directive with a selector `h3` and then use `ContentChildren` or `ViewChildren` to query for all of its instances from a parent component. Then use this info to genrate the TOC.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel The reason I am combing through the dom in the service is because this is actually HTML sent from a back-end API that gets injected as `[innerHTML]`. Normally yeah I wouldn't like to do this, but since the HTML comes back from a service I thought this was my only choice.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Would I need to attach this directive to all h3 elements I want to add to the table of contents? My problem is all of this HTML for my page is coming from a back-end API which I inject using `[innerHTML]` so I don't have the power to add directives. Maybe I am misunderstanding though.

Comment: @httpNick couldn't you just do that with the text that comes back from the server? Couldn't you just create a div and shove the contents as innerHTML and use that DOM node to search and find the h3 using the query methods on it? You could do that before any rendering happens so eliminate this synchronization

Comment: @httpNick It would be attached on its own if you use a selector `h3`.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović so luckily for me, my requirements changed and I am now getting a title sent from the back-end which signifies I add it to the table of contents. I tried the directive approach where I added `'h3'` as the selector, but it did not attach to the h3s that were dynamically generated. Maybe I am missing something? Looks like in the `createComponent` method within ViewContainerRef has a module parameter, am I supposed to pass in a module that imports my directive there perhaps?

Comment: Dynamically generated content via `innerHtml` or similar won't trigger Angular directive. Angular is compiled build-time.

Comment: Hmm, right so I don't think I'd be able to use a directive in the case of innerHtml. That'd need to use document queries, but then I am back to knowing when the HTML is rendered correct?

Answer (score 0):

For the part about the `setTimeout`, you can replace it with

```
this.ngZone.onMicrotaskEmpty.first()
    .subscribe(() => {...});
```

See line 446 in [Angular Material source code](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/8830486039d98d29a9dcf356bbcd7a8124a02478/src/lib/tooltip/tooltip.ts) for further explaination.

> Must wait for the message to be painted to the tooltip so that the overlay can properly calculate the correct positioning based on the size of the text.

I think this is the same case for you, too have to wait for the dom to be rendered.